# Using SQL to find continuous segments of event data (Gaps and Islands)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, statistics, analysis

I have a set of "event" data that has a start and end value.The data may overlap or be butted end to end (end value or one record matches the start value of another). I would like to find a nice solution to find the "islands" of events, i.e. find the spans where an event is occurring. The input and expected output tables below should help visualization.

To add additional complexity we may want to consider a tolerance (i.e. one event ending at 1.15 and another starting at 1.2 might be considered one continuous event.

I have tried to solve this problem by identifying all of the start events (those with no event starting where x event ends and then the end events. Then building the spans based on the start value from the start event plus the next end event value above it.

This does not work because the production data is too "real" and there are always fringe cases where the process doesn't fit.*

My current thinking is that it may be ideal to actually calculate the "gaps" then invert those gaps to find the continuous event spans.

*Note the actual production data is very large and very complex. There a hundreds of events with many being made up of very small fragments.

[image: gaps and islands data]

Comment: Are you on SQL Server 2012 or newer? There's quite a lot of improvement to window functions in 2012 that might help you.

Comment: I am sorry to say that this is still running on 2005.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to gaps-and-islands is to find all the places where there are gaps big enough to start an island, and then use that information to identify the islands.  This may be what you mean by "invert".

In your case, start with something like this:

```
with e as (   -- This CTE gets the previous end value
      select e.*,
             (select max(endValue)
              from events e2
              where e2.StartValue < e.StartValue
             ) as prev_endvalue
      from events
     ),
     e2 as (  -- This CTE assigns a flag identifying the start of an island
      select e.*,
             (case when endValue - prevendValue < 0.1 then 0 else 1 end) as IslandStart
      from e
     ),
     e3 as (  -- This CTE counts the number of island starts before each record, so all records in the island have the same value
      select e2.*,
             (select sum(IslandStart)
              from e2
              where e2.startValue <= e.startValue
             ) as IslandId
      from e2
     )
select IslandId, min(startValue) as startValue, max(endValue) as endValue)
from e3
group by IslandId;
```

The value of `0.5` in the definition of e2 is the threshold for the boundary conditions.  The code might need some tweaking if `StartValues` can be repeated.  The easiest solution in this case is to use `id` for the logic, if this orders the segments.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that is exactly what I meant by invert. I will put this to the test now.

Answer (score 0):

i'd try my luck with a table function:

```
create function fn_foobar() 
returns @Return table 
( id int primary key
, sv float
, ev float 
, unique (sv,ev)
) as
begin
  insert into @Return 
  select d.id, d.sv, d.ev 
  from events d left join events f on f.sv<d.sv and d.sv<=f.ev
  where f.id is null;

  declare @rowcnt int = 1;

  while (@rowcnt>0)
  begin
    update @Return
    set ev=n.ev
    from ( select r.id, max(c.ev) ev
           from @Return r join events c on c.sv<=r.ev and r.ev<c.ev
           group by r.id
         ) n
     where n.id=[@Return].id;
     set @rowcnt = @@ROWCOUNT;
  end;
return;
end;
```